# When not to use dynamic programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

I was reading about **dynamic programming** and I understood that we should not be using dynamic programming approach if the optimal solution of a problem does not contain the optimal solution of the subproblem.

The **Longest path problem** is very clear example on this and I understood why.

But I am not able to find out any other problem which is similar to longest path problem, where the subproblems's solution cannot be used for solving the optimal solution of parent. Can some one guide me?

Comment: You shouldn't use dynamic programming if it doesn't work. Here are a few examples: linear programming, linear equations, maximum matching, maximum flow.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks. what i really wanted was an example in which the subproblem fails, i will try too solve the examples you gave through dynamic programming and see if it fails (if i am able to split the above problems into subproblems)

Comment: Is longest path an instance where you _can_ or _cannot_ use DP?